# How to save multiple scores and data of a game in several UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

At the moment I'm working on my first iOS-game. It is a very simple game which consists of 3 ViewControllers (=VC). In the first VC, named "Complete Test", is the game-scene where the user has to press several UIButtons and at the end there is a final-score out of 100 points which is showed in the second VC (called "FinalCompleteTest") with all the stats of the game played.

Then, in the second VC the user should have the option to save his score by pressing the UIButton "Save Score". This button should trigger a segue to the third VC "ScoresCT" in which a TableView is embedded.

My end goal is that when the button "Save Score" is pressed, that the "custom" Prototype Cell (which I created)is duplicated and that all the scores which want to be saved by the user is shown in the TableView. 
Later on, I would also like to find a way that the date when the game was played is shown right beside the score of the game.

My swift knowledge is limited, but I know:

-how to transfer data from one VC to another VC
-how to save a Highscore (but unfortunately not multiple scores)

I have a good idea how it could work, but I don't know where to start.

How should I proceed? Thank you in advance for your help!

***code of file FinalCompleteTest.swift***

```
import UIKit

class FinalCompleteTest: UIViewController {

    //Components of Visualization in VC
    @IBOutlet weak var FinalScore: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var LeftPCT: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var CenterPCT: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var RightPCT: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var BadContactPCT: UILabel!



    //Total Final Score --> transferred from VC: CompleteTest
    var score = String()

    //Components for Calculation of Percantages --> transferred from VC: CompleteTest
    var Leftpct = Int()
    var Rightpct = Int()
    var Centerpct = Int()
    var Totalpct = Int()
    var BadContactpct = Int()


    //Calculations for Percantages

    lazy var endLeftpct: Int = 100 * Leftpct / Totalpct
    lazy var endRightpct: Int = 100 * Rightpct / Totalpct
    lazy var endCenterpct: Int = 100 * Centerpct / Totalpct
    lazy var endBadContactpct: Int = 100 * BadContactpct / 30




    // Transferring data from VC: FinalCompleteTest to VC: ScoresCT
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let ScoresCT = segue.destination as? ScoresCT
        ScoresCT?.scoresaved = String(score)}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FinalScore.text = score
            LeftPCT.text = String(endLeftpct) + "%"
            RightPCT.text = String(endRightpct) + "%"
            CenterPCT.text = String(endCenterpct) + "%"
            BadContactPCT.text = String(endBadContactpct) + "%"

        }
```

***code of file ScoresCT.swift***

```
import UIKit

class ScoresCT: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var scoresaved = String()       // var transferred from VC: FinalCompleteTest


    let date = ["14.05.2019"]


    // TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (date.count)}


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ScoresCTcell
        cell?.scoreSaved.text = String(scoresaved)
        return (cell!)
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }
    }
```

***code of file ScoresCTcell.swift***

```
import UIKit

class ScoresCTcell: UITableViewCell {


    //Components of Custom Prototype Cell
    @IBOutlet weak var datum: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var scoreSaved: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't do something like `let ScoresCT = segue.destination as? ScoresCT`. This is confusing and can cause problems. Name variables always with a starting lowercase letter `let scoresCT = segue.destination as? ScoresCT`. And `return` is not  a function. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see this mistake.